# Touch Hold Event In corona SDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I was wondering how I would check if the user has touched the screen, but is holding their touch down and is not moving.  Please help if you have anything I can go from.  Ive been looking around and have yet to find anything to handle this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use/modify this: (It's what Rob Miracle says)

```
local holding = false
local function enterFrameListener()
    if holding then
        -- Holding button
        -- Code here
        -- Code here
        -- Code here
    else
        -- Not holding
        -- Code here
        -- Code here
        -- Code here
    end
end

local function touchHandler( event )
    if event.phase == "began" then
        display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( event.target )
        event.target.isFocus = true
        Runtime:addEventListener( "enterFrame", enterFrameListener )
        holding = true
    elseif event.target.isFocus then
        if event.phase == "moved" then
        elseif event.phase == "ended" then
            holding = false
            Runtime:removeEventListener( "enterFrame", enterFrameListener )
            display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( nil )
            event.target.isFocus = false
        end
    end
    return true
end
```

I believe its obvious what touchHandler function is ^^

Answer (score 1):

You will need a touch listener added to either an object covering your whole screen or you can add it to the system's RunTime.

See this guide:  http://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/events/detectEvents/index.html#hit

Now, there are three "Phases" for these touch events.  You get one when the press starts ("began"), one if the person moves their finger ("moved") and when they stop touching, there is an "ended" phase.

Depending on what you are trying to do, if you are say moving something while holding the button down, then you can set a flag like:

```
 if event.phase == "began" then
      pressed = true
 elseif event.phase == "ended" then
      pressed = false
 end
```

Then where ever you're moving you can check to see "if pressed then move".

Comment: Right now I have an eventlistener working so that if I touch the object it processes its function, but if I just hold it down, like a simple button, it doesnt continuously process it, which is the effect im looking for.  I'm wanting it to continue to trigger if its being pushed.

Comment: Right you will need something like a Runtime "enterFrame" listener to do whatever it is you want to do that monitors the status of the flag.  There will be no additional events generated saying "Im still holding this down".

Comment: so like a timer looping and an event triggering a processing variable or something that allows the timer to process something?

Comment: Right. If you setup a runtime listener on the enterFrame event, you will get one of these events 30 times per second for a 30fps app or 60 times a second for a 60fps app.

In your touch listener, on event.phase == "began", you set a flag saying that the button is pressed.  Then in your runtime listener, do the work you need to do when the button is down.  Then in the event.phase == "ended" clear the flag.