# is there a touch and hold event in Corona sdk, If not then how to do that

Tags: touch, coronasdk, corona-storyboard

is there a touch and hold event in Corona sdk, If not then how to do that. for example. i want to increase the radius of a circle while holding anywhere on the screen, and without moving. how to do that.
'

thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try (as I know you can't change radius so I use `xScale` and `yScale` to increase circle)

```
local circle = display.newCircle(  display.contentCenterX, display.contentCenterY, 50 )
step = 0.02

local holding = false
local function enterFrameListener()
    if holding then
        -- Holding button
        circle.xScale = circle.xScale + step
        circle.yScale = circle.yScale + step
    else
        -- Not holding
        -- Code here
    end
end

local function touchHandler( event )
    if event.phase == "began" then
        Runtime:addEventListener( "enterFrame", enterFrameListener )
        holding = true  
    elseif event.phase == "ended" or event.phase == "moved" then
        holding = false
        Runtime:removeEventListener( "enterFrame", enterFrameListener )
    end
    return true
end

Runtime:addEventListener( "touch", touchHandler )
```

The code borrow from [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16473220/touch-hold-event-in-corona-sdk) from stackoverflow.com.

Comment: it is not working. what i want to do is increase the circle radius continuously. i saw your game "Square", the same idea for the rectangle there. if it is working can you help explaining how this can work??

Comment: I have improved my answer. It works. In my first game [THE SQUARE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wordpress.ldurniat.thesquare&hl=pl) I use transition to increase square as remember but I'm not sure.

Comment: that is perfect. it solved my problem.where i can get this knowledge as you.

Comment: My knowledge comes from game programming practice (I'm working on my second game now), [Corona forum](https://forums.coronalabs.com), online tutorials (Corona and Lua) and books in this order.